# Form required section in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

there is required section in my form also I want to send successfully text after click of submit button. But problem is here when I click submit button, it shows successfully text no matter form is correct or not. Can you help me about that ? I am beginner :)

My react code here

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    surname: "",
    phone: "",
    email: "",
    comments: "",
    // isValid: true,
    succesfully: ""
  };

  /* preventSending = async (e) => {
    await this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    if (
      this.state.name === "" ||
      this.state.surname === "" ||
      this.state.phone === "" ||
      this.state.email === "" ||
      this.state.comments === ""
    ) {
      this.setState({ isValid: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isValid: false });
    }
  };*/

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      succesfully: `${this.state.name} you have sent successfully `
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="">
        <form>
          <label htmlFor="name">
            Name :
            <input
              onChange={this.preventSending}
              id="name"
              name="name"
              type="text"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="surname">
            Surname :
            <input
              onChange={this.preventSending}
              id="surname"
              name="surname"
              type="text"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="phone">
            Phone :
            <input
              onChange={this.preventSending}
              id="phone"
              name="phone"
              type="tel"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="email">
            Email :
            <input
              onChange={this.preventSending}
              id="email"
              name="email"
              type="email"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="textArea">
            Comments :
            <textarea
              onChange={this.preventSending}
              id="textarea"
              name="comments"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <br />
          <button
            type="submit"
            // disabled={this.state.isValid}
            onClick={this.handleSubmit}
          >
            Send details{" "}
          </button>
        </form>

        <p>{this.state.succesfully}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It says I have to add more details but I explained everything clear.

Comment: Why have u commented a block of code using "//"!? You should use "/* text here */"

Comment: Thank you for correcting, but I think it doesn't affect anything. I just want to find how can I check my submit is successfully return or not

Comment: Yes I know it doesn’t affect anything but I was just telling a thing which u were doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

I have to go through your code and try to resolve the errors and get the proper output.

I see that you take the direct state object and update its value, I just corrected that part and also add one error flag in it, so that you can display one informational error message while you click the button without adding the data.

Apart from that, in your form, you take one button which has submit type.
As of now I simply update it with type=button, as type=submit will submit the form and redirect us to new URL.

Please let me know if it is useful to you or not.

here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            surname: "",
            phone: "",
            email: "",
            comments: "",
            // isValid: true,
            succesfully: "",
            error: "",
        };
    }

    /* preventSending = async (e) => {
        await this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        if (
        this.state.name === "" ||
        this.state.surname === "" ||
        this.state.phone === "" ||
        this.state.email === "" ||
        this.state.comments === ""
        ) {
        this.setState({ isValid: true });
        } else {
        this.setState({ isValid: false });
        }
    };*/

    handleChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value,
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        if (
            this.state.name !== "" &&
            this.state.surname !== "" &&
            this.state.phone !== "" &&
            this.state.email !== "" &&
            this.state.comments !== ""
        ) {
            // check valid email or not with regex
            const regexp = /^([\w\.\+]{1,})([^\W])(@)([\w]{1,})(\.[\w]{1,})+$/;
            let isValidEmail = regexp.test(this.state.email) ? true : false;

            if (isValidEmail) {
                this.setState({
                    succesfully: `${this.state.name} you have sent successfully `,
                    error: "",
                });
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    succesfully: "",
                    error: "Please add proper email",
                });
            }
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    succesfully: "",
                    error: "Please add proper data",
                });
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="">
                <form>
                    <label htmlFor="name">
                        Name :
                        <input
                        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                        id="name"
                        name="name"
                        type="text"
                        value={this.state.name}
                        required
                        />
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <label htmlFor="surname">
                        Surname :
                        <input
                        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                        id="surname"
                        name="surname"
                        type="text"
                        value={this.state.surname}
                        required
                        />
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <label htmlFor="phone">
                        Phone :
                        <input
                        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                        id="phone"
                        name="phone"
                        type="tel"
                        value={this.state.phone}
                        required
                        />
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <label htmlFor="email">
                        Email :
                        <input
                        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                        id="email"
                        name="email"
                        type="email"
                        value={this.state.email}
                        required
                        />
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <label htmlFor="textArea">
                        Comments :
                        <textarea
                        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                        id="textarea"
                        name="comments"
                        value={this.state.comments}
                        required
                        />
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <button
                        // type="submit" // use this while you want to submit your form
                        type="button" // I use button to call handleSubmit method and display message
                        // disabled={this.state.isValid}
                        onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                    >
                        Send details
                    </button>
                </form>

                <p>{this.state.succesfully}</p>
                <p>{this.state.error}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: That's cool bro, but as you can see when we are writing email section any text it will accept it. I checked this code and example if I write test in email input this app shows successfull message. So I want to figure it :)

Comment: For that, you have you validate your email with Regex validation. I will update that in my code soon.

Comment: @Mehi I have updated my code with email validation as well, now you can check and if you like, you can give an upvote to my answer as well. Thanks :)

Comment: It needs at least 15 reputation but thank you so much for spending your time :). I will appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I see that the function prevent sending that you created should work except you misplaced the isValid argument:

```
function ValidateEmail(email) 
{
 if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email))
  {
    return true
  }
    return false
}

if (
      this.state.name === "" ||
      this.state.surname === "" ||
      this.state.phone === "" ||
      this.state.email === "" ||
      this.state.comments === "" ||
      !validateEmail(this.state.email)
    ) {
      this.setState({ isValid: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isValid: true });
    }
```

also uncomment disabled and isValid which should be false at the begginning:

```
// disabled={this.state.isValid}
// isValid = false
```

Comment: thank you so much for adding email section, first all of them working fine but I can not figure out email section. So its clear to see how can email input works :)

Comment: And when I try it doesn't work, Can I write this.state.email === (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)) => like that, Because I think it has to be check something. In my code I wrote below if section for just disabled submit button but when user fill something in email input without this (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)) submit also accept this input and show successfull message

Comment: @Niyameddin no you can't compare it like this, I made some changes try to copy that function now